# How to get root node while deleting from singly linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list, root

I was wondering how this function is getting the root node while trying to delete a  node from a singly linked list. I understand the whole deletion part.

```
class LinkedList { 
    LinkedListNode root; 

    // Remove the nodes which contain data equal to obj 
    void deleteNode(Object obj) { 
        // special case for root 
        if( root.data.equals(obj) ) { 
            root = root.next; 
        }  
        LinkedListNode current = root; 
        // iterate through list looking for obj 
        while( current.next != null ) { 
            // match found 
            if( current.next.data.equals(obj) ) { 
                // cut out the node 
                current.next = current.next.next; 
            } 
            current = current.next; 
        }
    }
} 

private class LinkedListNode { 
    Object data; 
    LinkedListNode next; 
}
```

I'm not sure why just by creating a LinkedListNode root, it refers to the root node. Clear and easy to understand help would be much appreciated.

Ff theoretically I didn't create the LinkedListNode root, could I just pass in an extra parameter to the delete function, and specify which one is the head based on its data?

```
LinkedListNode deleteNode(LinkedListNode head, int d) {
    LinkedListNode n = head;
    if (n.data == d) {
        return head.next; /* moved head */
    }
    while (n.next != null) {
        if (n.next.data == d) {
            n.next = n.next.next;
            return head; /* head didn’t change */
        }
        n = n.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question...

`LinkedListNode root` is a private member of the class `LinkedList`, presumably initialized in a constructor and/or elsewhere in an `AddNode` function or something. Once you have the member `root` initialized (and referencing the root node of the list), functions like `DeleteNode` are allowed to use it, such as 
`if( root.data.equals(obj) ) { root = root.next; }`

I hope this helps somewhat...

Comment: could you explain to me how you would initialize the root node then? thanks = )

Comment: You will probably want to do this with a constructor, which is the standard way to initialize member variables for classes. Take a look at this MSDN page, which gives all the details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx

In your case, you'll need to initialize root with something like `root = new LinkedListNode` and provide initial `data` and `next` values

Answer (score 0):

It's not automatic. "root" is a class variable for the LinkedList class, which is to say that every instance of the LinkedList class has an attribute called root that is some LinkedListNode. You can use and/or reference this anywhere in the class definition.

The root node will be specified when an instance of the LinkedList class is created, in its constructor (which I'm assuming exists somewhere). If it isn't, there won't be any reference to the LinkedList you created and it will be all but useless.

To answer the second part of your question, you could write such a function but there is no need to. It would be redundant; you can just use the reference to the root node.